# Is it possible to determine the number of states in a minimal DFA without explicitly constructing it?

Tags: finite-automata, dfa

Is there any short answer or formula for determining the number of states in a DFA according to any language? more precisely **is it possible to determine the number of states in a minimal DFA without explicitly constructing it?**

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know about "short", but there is a heuristic that can be used. This is basically a restatement of the result of the [Myhill-Nerode Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem).

Given an alphabet and a language that is a subset of all strings over that alphabet, say that two strings *x* and *y* are equivalent if for any other string *z* the concatenations *xz* and *yz* are either both in the language or both not in the language. (note that *z* can be the empty string)

> For example, if the alphabet is just `0` and `1`, and the language is "all strings that end in `11`", then the strings "`0010`" and "`1110`" are equivalent, because if *z* ends in `11` then both concatenations are in the language and if *z* does not end in `11`, neither concatenation is in the language. Note that the string "`0001`" is not equivalent to those other two, because if *z* is "`1`", then the concatenation "`0001`" + "`1`" is in the language, but the concatenation "`0010`" + "`1`" is not in the language.

Then, the number of states in a minimal DFA for the language is the number of equivalence classes under this definition of "equivalent".

> Following the example from before, the equivalence classes are "strings that do not end in a `1`" (so, strings that end in `0` or the empty string), "strings that end in a `1` but do not end in `11`", and "strings that end in `11`". Therefore, the minimal DFA for this language consists of three states.

The only application I know of is the proof that the regular language for "numbers in some fixed base *b* that are divisible by *n*" requires at a minimum *n* states.